# InputStream returns java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

Im trying to download file from webservice.

the method is post and im sending json to service.

this is my code :

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();


            DataOutputStream printout;


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");  

            conn.connect();  
            //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("Id", 25);


            // Send POST output.
            printout = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream ());
            printout.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));
            printout.flush ();
            printout.close ();

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();


            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();

            Log.d("lenghtOfFile : ", lenghtOfFile + "byte");
            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());


            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("backup.db");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

status code is 200 and the size of lenghtOfFile is the file im trying to

download , but at this line :

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

program gives error :

```
05-28 09:11:25.513: E/Error:(627): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/api/Values
```

i even changed the buffer size to content size but still no hope.

Comment: Think that you cannot use url.openStream()) after connect() or openConnection() Which you do both and the latter twice. Why? Use getOutputStream(); Remove the .close();.

Comment: thanks for respond can u elaborate how can i achieve this?

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: ive done what u mentioned and changed to this :
input = conn.getInputStream();
and problem goes away.